# Definite integral12

Tags: calculus

If $$\int_{3}^{a-1} f(x) dx =2\int_{2}^3 f(2x -1) dx $$
Find the value of a ?
My turn :
$$L.H.S =2\int_{5}^{2a-3} f(2x-1) dx  $$
But i did not go on ?

Comment: Try the substitution $u=2x-1$, $du=2\,dx$.

Comment: You seem to have replaced $x$ by $2x-1$ and you have adjusted the derivative correctly.  However it's a bit confusing doing it this way.  If you try substituting $x=2u-1$ on the LHS instead instead I think you will see where you went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Performing the change of variables on the RHS, $u=2x-1$, we just get the equality
$$
\int_3^{a-1}f(x)\mathrm dx=\int_3^5f(x)\mathrm dx
$$
and $a=6$.